# Find elements in many series below threshold value

Tags: python-3.x

I have many time series (10'000 with 3 to 10'000 data points each), each with a distinct threshold. I need to know which ones contain values which are below or above a certain threshold.

Example:

```
threshold_data = [
    # Name Threshold data-points..
    ['ds1', 90,    91, 92, 95],
    ['ds2', 85,    91, 84, 95],
]
```

If the operation is `<`, I expect `ds2` as output because it has `84` which is less than the threshold of `85`. For the operation `>`, both data sets should be returned. For `==` none.

I know I can load the data into a Pandas DataFrame and then compare each data point like so:

```
COL_NAME, COL_THRESHOLD = 'Name', 'Threshold'
df_t = pd.DataFrame(threshold_data, columns=[COL_NAME, COL_THRESHOLD, 't1', 't2', 't3'])

for i in range(1, 4):
    key = f't{i}'
    print(key, df_t[df_t[key] < df_t[COL_THRESHOLD]])
```

but this isn't efficient when I have 10'000 data points.

I tried to compare the `t#` subset against the threshold value per row `(df_t.loc['t1':] < df_t[COL_THRESHOLD])` but doesn't work since Pandas tries to compare a series (`t#` in each row) with a single value.

I was considering to copy the threshold so I get two DataFrames with the same size, cut the data points out with `df_t.loc[:, 't1':]` and compare each index but that would need a lot of memory.

I could try to group by threshold value but there will be many different values so this would create a slow loop in Python. I will already have a loop for each operation (<, <=, >, >=, ==).

Is there an efficient way to perform this operation in Python? Pandas would be preferred but other solutions are acceptable as well.

Answer (score 0):

To key to solving this is to reduce the number of data points to a single value, depending on the operation.

Let's say you want to find all rows where there are data points below the threshold. For this operation, you don't need to check all data points but only the minimum since all values above that don't affect the result. To get the minimum per row:

```
min_per_row = df_t.loc[:, 't1':].min(axis=1)
```

where `[:, 't1':]` selects every row (`:`) and then all including and to the right of `t1` (i.e. all data points in the time series). `min(axis=1)` gets the minimum per row; `min()` would return the minimum per column.

This gives one value per row which you can then compare against the threshold column. To get all rows with values below the threshold:

```
df_t[min_per_row < df_t[COL_THRESHOLD]]
```